# How to access camera or gallery in android Kiosk Mode app?

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

i am using kiosk mode in my android app. Here kiosk service should be called every two second  and the app open for every two seconds. My app needs to access gallery or camera app. But my app does not let me access these things because every two seconds it comes to foreground if we try to go to other applications. Now my problem is i need to access camera and gallery in kiosk service which should be called for every two seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Afaiu you are using background service which runs continuously in gap of 2 second.

Instead of using background service i would suggest you should use screen pinning option for android lollipop or more devices. To get more information regarding this you can read http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/ .

Also ,you have to make your application a launcher application,so that everytime user presses the launcher icon your application starts.

To disable power on/off button you can use System Dialog Disable feature.

By using this you can get following benefits :- 
1) Power consumptions/Memory usage is minimized.
2) According to your usage you can disable/enable the kiosk mode.
3) You can start the other application from your application by disabling the kiosk mode application.

Regards
Ajay